# SettingWithCopyWarning with Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dataframe consisting of some actions that users do on the app. I want to add a new column, and store the previous action of the user, using a `grupby` and `shift`:

dataframe:

```
session_id | action
100        | click
100        | buy
101        | open
101        | buy
```

So I use:

```py
df['prev_action'] = df.groupby('session_id')['action'].shift()
```

Result:

```
session_id | action | prev_action
100        | click  | NA
100        | buy    | click
101        | open   | NA
101        | buy    | open
```

It works fine and the result seems fine too, but I get the `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
>
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

I know a littl about `SettingWithCopyWarning`, and I want to know how can I change my code to write a better one and don't get the warning (or should I just ignore the warning in this case?)

Comment: Your dataframe is a copy of another one. Try `df = df.copy()` before assignment.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yeah, it fixed the warning. Thanks.